# Write linq query results to .csv file mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

im trying to write a linq query that searches stuff in the database. if it gets the data it should return the results to a .csv file. this is my query

```
var query = from a in db.User where a.id.Equals(table.id)
            select a;
```

im struggling to find how i can use this query to write results to database.
im using c# mvc

**Update**

Right now this is my method:

```
public FileContentResult ConnectToDatabase(Requests uc)
    {
        Context db = new Context();
        var query = (from a in db.Request
                     where a.Idnumber.Equals(uc.Idnumber)
                     select a);

        string csv = string.Concat(from re in query
                                  select string.Format("{0},{1},{2}\n", re.Idnumber, re.RequestStartDate, re.RequestEndDate));


        return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(csv), "text/csv", "Report.csv");

    }
```

and i am getting a this error: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object)"

Comment: You are asking about two separate writes...to a csv and to a database.  Which one is it?  In addition, the query seems fine.  What does that have to do with writing to a csv?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: @DavidL please check my update, i want the results returned from my query to be written to the csv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem here is that `query` is an `IQueryable`, so when you do `select string.Format("{0},{1},{2}\n ...` Entity Framework will try to convert that to SQL and it won't be able to.

So there are a few ways you can solve this:

1) Keep the `IQueryable` but build the CSV rows in a way that EF can translate to SQL:

```
var csv = string.Concat(query.Select(re => re.IdNumber + "," + re.RequestStartDate + "," + re.RequestEndDate + "\n));
```

2) Materialize `query` into a `List` so that the `string.Format` call is done in C#, not SQL.

```
var query = (from a in db.Request
                     where a.Idnumber.Equals(uc.Idnumber)
                     select a).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you lots @Pedro, I used .AsEnumerable() on the query